# How to delete rows that comes from loc function ? (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete rows which are includes specific values.

```
data.loc[data['Column_3'].isin(['1'])
```

But i want to keep 1000 of them.

```
data.loc[data['Column_3'].isin(['1'])][0:1000]
```

How can i apply this into my dataset?
Actually i want to see 1 in column_3 but only 1000 of them. But i want to see all rows which are not include 1.

Comment: nope, i changed my question can you look again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `drop` with index values outside range per condition:

```
df = data.drop(data[data['Column_3'] == '1'].index[1000:])
```

Or:

```
df = data.drop(data.index[data['Column_3'] == '1'][1000:])
```

Comment: i cant keep other rows which not includes 1 in column_3 with this solution.